# Setup Alfresco as provider for OAuth

Tags: java, web-services, rest, alfresco

I want to acces to alfresco as a third party app. All i found is how to use it as OAuth client. Is there any suggestions on how to setup Alfresco as a service provider ?

Comment: AFAIK you can not do that !

Comment: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/pra/1/concepts/pra-authentication.html